# It keeps showing unknown tag error with {% for post in all_posts %} and {% endfor %} when i run it with flask

Tags: python

```
 include "header.html" %}

  <!-- Page Header -->
  <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1470092306007-055b6797ca72?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=668&q=80')">
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
          <div class="site-heading">
            <h1>Angela's Blog</h1>
            <span class="subheading">A collection of Angela's random musings.</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        {% for post in all_posts %}
        <div class="post-preview">
          <a href="{{ url_for('show_post', index=post.id) }}">
            <h2 class="post-title">
              {{post.title}}
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
              {{post.subtitle}}
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">{{post.author}}</a>
            on {{post.date}}</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}


        <!-- New Post -->
        <div class="clearfix">
          <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Create New Post</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
    {% include "footer.html" %}
```

It isn't show the website It keeps showing unknown tag error with {% for post in all_posts %} and {% endfor %} when i run it with flask. i cant add any more detail
It isn't show the website It keeps showing unknown tag error with {% for post in all_posts %} and {% endfor %} when i run it with flask. i cant add any more detail
It isn't show the website It keeps showing unknown tag error with {% for post in all_posts %} and {% endfor %} when i run it with flask. i cant add any more detail
It isn't show the website It keeps showing unknown tag error with {% for post in all_posts %} and {% endfor %} when i run it with flask. i cant add any more detail

Comment: `{% for ... %}` is a basic Flask tag; I don't know why it would be unknown.  Can you edit the question to include the full error message display?

Comment: TypeError: 'method' object is not iterable

Comment: Sounds like you're expecting `all_posts` to be a list, but it's actually a function.  Can you show us the view code?